# Sweet Alert using AngularJS 2 and templateing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sweetalert

i have a small app that works great, when not using angualr templating. However i need to now export the code into it. Sweet Alert should be called when a button is clicked. So when the button is called through the template sweet alert is meant to pop up, but nothing happens. I am assuing it is something to do with even binding as the app loads the code after the DOM has intializied.

```
//app.component.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <form>
     <button type="button" class="ticket_button">Book</button>
    </form>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
//some app logic here
}


//index.html
//i have not included the normal header stuff here, however the my-app class shows the button 

<html<body>
    <my-app class="main_ticket">Loading...</my-app>
</body></html>

// I have tried to use event binding from Jquery $('.main_ticket').on('change', '.ticket_button', function() {//logic here}, but it also didn't work 

<script>
 //Sweet Alert call
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function(){
  swal("Here's a message!");
};
</script>
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-sweetalert2

Comment: Good point by Stallion; In most cases you shouldn't use the jQuery packages, but try to look for angular packages of the libraries you are using. There is almost always one available.

Comment: By the way: Sweetalert2 now supports typescript natively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use ***Life Cylcle Hooks*** to get it working:

```
export class AppComponent implements ngAfterViewInit{
//some app logic here

     ngAfterViewInit(){
       document.querySelector('button').onclick = function(){
          swal("Here's a message!");
       };
     }

}
```

Or better to use ***angular2's Standard events***:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <form>
     <button type="button" (click)="popAlert();" class="ticket_button">Book</button>
    </form>
    `
})
```

Now in the Class:

```
export class AppComponent {
//some app logic here
    popAlert(){
      swal("Here's a message!");
    }
}
```

Comment: i have spent two days banging my head on this. Thank you so much, do you have any recommendations to Angular 2 resources? beyond the official documentation?

Comment: Well i follow some online videos and read docs trying to be there, still infant in angular2.